# Notepad++ Regular Expression Condition Replacement

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, notepad++, replace

I have a set of SQL script that wants to change schema.

```
create table Service.Table1 (col1 varchar(100));
create table Operation.Table2 (col1 varchar(100));
create table Support.Table3 (col1 varchar(100));
```

However, the schema is going to change

```
Service -> Sev
Operation -> Opn
Support -> Spt
```

The search regular expression is easy `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_]+)`

However, how to do the conditional replacement in Notepad++ or other tools if they can?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple word search and replace in notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a predefined set of the schemas, you may use the conditional replacement in Notepad++ like this:

**Find**: `(?:(?<a>Service)|(?<b>Operation)|(?<c>Support))\.(?<n>[A-Z0-9_]+)`
**Replace**: `(?{a}Sev:(?{b}Opn:Spt)).$+{n}`

*Match Case* must be ticked *off*, and *Regular expression* must be *on*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would run replace 3 times, once for each schema name:

```
Find:
create table Service\.
Replace with:
create table Svc.

Find:
create table Support\.
Replace with:
create table Spt.

Find:
create table Operation\.
Replace with:
create table Opn.
```

Or here is one that uses groups references:

```
Find:
Service(\.[^\s]+)(.*)
Replace with:
Svc\1\2
```

Here `\1` will hold the dot operator and the table name and \2 holds the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ regex implementation is not really powerfull; so,

> other tools if they can?

Here is a way to do it:

```
perl -pi.back -e '%tr=(Service=>"Sev",Operation=>"Opn",Support=>"Spt");s/(?<=create table )(\w+)/$tr{$1}/e;' TheFile
```

You can add any number of `Original => 'Modified'` as you want within the hash `%tr`.

`TheFile` will be backuped into `TheFile.back` before processing.