# Multiple word search and replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I replace several different words all at once in Notepad++?

For example;

I have "good", "great" and "fine" and I want to replace them with "bad", "worse" and "not", respectively, all at once.

I know that I can replace them one by one, but the problem I am facing requires that I replace a lot of words, which is not convenient to do.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Install [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin from Plugin Manager.

### Create a file with your substitutions (e.g., C:/Temp/Substitutions.txt), separate values with space:

```
good bad
great worse
fine not
```

### Create a new script:

```
with open('C:/Temp/Substitutions.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

### Run the new script against the text you want to substitute.

Comment: Works well for simple search and replace. Doesn't work if the things to be replaced are regex itself.

Comment: @Rishi For the purposes of this question _simple search replace_ was enough. _Regex search replace_ can be achieved by using `editor.rereplace(s[0], s[1])` instead. Or even better `editor.pyreplace` to leverage full Python regex support.

Comment: How do I run this Python script across multiple files in NotePadd++?

Answer (score 69):

Try a regular expression replace of `(good)|(great)|(fine)` with `(?1bad)(?2worse)(?3not)`.

The search looks for either of three alternatives separated by the `|`. Each alternative has its own capture brackets. The replace uses the conditional form **?Ntrue-expression:false-expression** where **N** is decimal digit, the clause checks whether capture expression **N** matches.

Tested in Notepad++ 8.5.8 (and previously in Notepad++ 6.3).

Since this answer was first written the Notepad community has created the [Notepad++ Online User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/) and it contains a good description of the [Substitution Conditionals](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#substitution-conditionals) used here.

The replacement string above can be extended to have replacements for the **false-expression**s. For example `(?1bad:[1])(?2worse:[2])(?3not:[3])`. These false expressions are not very useful, but they provide a demonstration of what is happening in each replacement. Using this replacement on the string:

```
+good+great+fine+
```

yields the result:

```
+bad[2][3]+[1]worse[3]+[1][2]not+
```

The original answer includes the information below. The three links checked and are still valid on 2024-01-02, the ZIP file was not checked:

> You can find good documentation, about the new PRCE Regular
> Expressions,  used by N++, since the 6.0 version, at the TWO addresses
> below :
>
> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html
>
> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html
>
> The FIRST one concerns the syntax of regular expressions in SEARCH
>
> The SECOND one concerns the syntax of regular expressions in
> REPLACEMENT
>
> And, if you can understand "written French", I made a tutorial about
> PCRE regular expressions, stored in the personal site of Christian
> Cuvier  (cchris), at the address below :
>
> http://oedoc.free.fr/Regex/TutorielRegex.zip

(Extracted from a posting by **THEVENOT Guy** at http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/ca059a0a/ )

Comment: Amazing! Could you add the source? I could not find this anywhere in the documentation. I use notepad++'s regex replace frequently and I'm curious if I could get more some cool stuff

Comment: index start at 0 for me in 6.4.5

Comment: awesome never knew about this, use notepad++ for regex replace constantly.

Comment: This is awesome! But, do you know how to make it use the output of the previous search/replace for the next one? I assumed that's what it was doing because of the |, but it's not.

Comment: But how could we do this for a huge list? I have about 100 elements separated by ,'s and the other list separated by a comma too.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to run the substitution on **several files**. Based on [Mauricio Morales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197147/5734097)'s answer, I created the following script.

```
with open('C:/Temp/Substitutions.txt') as f:
    files = notepad.getFiles()
    for file in files:
        notepad.activateFile(file[0])
        for l in f:
            s = l.split()
            editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
        f.seek(0) # Reset file input stream
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're replacing the same words in several different files all the time, recording your action once using [these buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kKVz.png) and saving it as a macro will be helpful. *Notepad++

Comment: What do you mean by "*`Notepad++`"?