# Notepad++ Change Date Format to MON

Tags: date, notepad++

I have a load of files with the date in the format `01-Feb-01` however need in the format `01/02/01`. I've come across examples where the month is just 2 digits but how do i handle months with 3 letters?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to rename files, or do you want to change dates on lines within the files? A date like `01/02/01` is confusing, should it be interpreted as **mm/yy/dd** or as **dd/mm/yy** or **yy/mm/dd**, etc.

Comment: Want to change dates on lines within files. Btw I agree the date format is not perfect, its just what I have.

Comment: Notepad++ has a 'replace in files' facility within its search and replace commands. You could replace `-Feb-` with `/02/` and then eleven more similar replaces for the other months. It may be better to do a regular expression replace such as `(\d)-Feb-(\d)` with `\1/02/\2` to avoid (eg) `early-may-flies` changing to `early-05-flies`. But all are hard work. Better, I think, it to extend the question into a programming language you are familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that there's no other way, than to make 12 replace in files for every month, with regex like this:

find what:

```
(\d{2})-jan-(\d{2})
(\d{2})-feb-(\d{2})
```

replace with:

```
\1/01/2
\1/02/2
```

And so on (ignore case option on, ofcourse). 
If there's a way to replace a list of subpatterns with a list of replacements, I'd happy to get to know it. But for now it's all I've got :).

Comment: @rikozoid, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946