# Python Script for search and replace with "match words only" option

Tags: python, replace

Py File: named Portuguesetranslator.py

```
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editor.replace(s[0],s[1])
```

I created that into Python Script inside of Notepad++

Then i have my "database" called Portuguesetranslator.txt

And is separated into

Result*Resultado*
Event*Evento*
.... and more 1k++ exapmles like this

Then the process i do is.. 
I open a 3rd tab... copy an text from the internet.. and place into that tab.. then i run the script by pressing plugin/python script/portuguesetranslator

And its run in my entire document and search and replace ..

So what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your text file? It would help to understand more.

Comment: Helton Por favor me ajuda cara! o Brazil precisa de voce ! :(

Comment: @RenanCidale no meu perfil tem correio eletrônico, só não garanto ajuda rápida!

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expressions. `\b` is the word boundary command in a regular expression. It means that at that point in the regular expression, you must be on a word boundary (not in the middle of a word). You can wrap this around your `s[0]`:

```
import re
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editor = re.sub(r'\b' + s[0] + r'\b', s[1], editor)
```

**Edit** - for notepad++, it looks like you want the last line to be this:

```
editor.pyreplace(r'\b' + s[0] + r'\b', s[1])
```

Comment: so i just need to copy that script and replace for mine?.. and for the database i keep writing with the same model? Result*Resultado* ?

Comment: so .. i replaced.. and tried to run the script.. but it doesnt translate anything..

Comment: in the text file .. how the words must be placed?? result*resultado* ?

Comment: import re
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        re.sub(r'\b' + s[0] + r'\b', s[1], editor)  where is everythihng that it is in the script file

Comment: Yes .. its my whole script.. i run that script in my text file .. that script its based in the database founded in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt as you can see in the script

Comment: is there any way that i can have your skype.. or something.. so i can show my files.. because this comment system its impossible to write .. i tried to replace what you just sent to me.. but still.. when i run that script again.. nothing happens.. i dont know if the problem is in the Portuguesetranslator.txt file..

Comment: btw.. what the translated_file.txt means? im not understanding this code you are saying.. and another thing.. when i use my current code.. to search and replace.. he does the things very well.. but the problem is when i face for example.. "Result" or "Event" because the replace would be "Resultado" and "Evento".. wich means that he ill replace for Resultado .. all good.. but if i run the script one more time.. the ill have the result of "Resultadoado".. because he found "Result" again in the text.. i hope i could make myself clear

Comment: remember that.. i do want to translate.. but only following the sentences im setting as the example.. thats why i have the Portuguesetranslator.txt file.. thats why im using the search and replace function.. and my old script.. i just need to copy the text i want to search and replace.. place into notepad++ then run the script.. by plugin/pythonscript/portuguesetranslator.py .. then the script runs into all the text.. and do the magic ...

Comment: Ill Edit my post.. take a look please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad  Im using the script that you see in that example.. i copied..

Comment: @RenanCidale please don't write so many comments, we're not having time to think :P

Comment: @Renan - I had a bug in my original code. Can you try the original version again? Other than that, I think it's a notepad++ plugin issue, of which I'm totally unfamiliar.

Comment: @heltonbiker Por favor me ajuda !

Comment: that thing u just updated starts a loop.. and closes the notepad++

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @JoshG79 didn't quite work for me (N++ 7.5.1), only the last line needed to be modified:

`with open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IPL\WIP\EnergyTagSubstitutions.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split()
        editor.rereplace(r'\b' + s[0] + r'\b', s[1])`