# Regex replace from |

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this regular expression:

```
'(1|2|6|8|13|14|17|20|42|53)'
```

This will match the numbers listed.  Helpful being that I only want those specific numbers.

However, I want to do a replace on these based on the number.  As an example, `'1'` would become `'STL'` while `'17'` would become `'PHX'`

Is there a way I can do this in a single Regular Expression?  If not, how might I do this in Notepad++ without doing 10 different search and replace operations?

Comment: Regexes alone can't do that. Use a small script (Perl, Python, whatever you like).

Comment: I don't believe you can, a simple find and replace would work just as easily for this situation, since you aren't using your capture group.

Comment: Just do the 10 search and replace operations, record a macro if you need to do it multiple times. It's probably faster than writing a script/plugin.

Comment: @Robadob Is there a way to disable the popup that says "X occurrences were replaced"?

Comment: The only way I can see that happening is by spamming the replace button, rather than clicking replace all, but then you may have an issue with knowing when to stop.

Comment: See this SO answer for a method with one complex regular expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946

Comment: @TimPietzcker More recent versions of Notepad++ can achieve what is wanted. See the answer just added.