# Notepad++ use both regular expressions and extended search

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need to find all `\r\n` that do not precede the letter M;
Seems I can't do this:

```
\r\n[^M]
```

I can only do `\r\n` with extended search selected or `[^M]` with regular expressions selected; but not together.

Comment: The regular expression support in Notepad++ is notoriously poor. Use another tool instead (e.g. grep, which has versions for Windows too, or another text editor).

Comment: @Cameron: Let's not get into a religious debate, as I have no problem with tools besides NP++; but according to who, what cited source(s) etcetera?  NP++ is actually quite capable of addressing the OP's need.

Comment: @J0e3gan: Sorry, I don't mean to diminish Notepad++. I use it daily myself. It's just that I gave up on its regex capabilities long ago :-)

Comment: @Cameron Notepad++ has extensive regular expression capabilities, perhaps you are thinking of an old and pre-PCRE version. See its regular expression documentation via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Aha, that explains it. I've never tried version 6.0+ (didn't know it existed!). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

You should instead use this regex:

```
\R(?!M)
```

**Explanation:**

- `\R` Any Unicode newline sequence.
- `(?!M)` **Negative Lookahead**: Assert "M" cannot be matched.

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` is valid with *Regular expression* checked in the Find tab too - i.e. not just with *Extended* checked: why not just use `\r\n[^M]` with *Regular expression* checked?

Given the following test text...

```
whatever
M
whatever
G
foo
```

..., `\r\n[^M]` yields the expected results below...

```
Search "\r\n[^M]" (3 hits in 1 file)
  new  2 (3 hits)
    Line 2: M
    Line 3: whatever
    Line 4: G
```

..., the matches being at the ends of the matched lines of course.

Comment: @Cameron: It's a common misconception in my experience - that *Extended* and *Regular expression* are mutually exclusive in NP++ finds/replaces: they are not in that *Regular expression* supports what *Extended* covers too.  I just think of *Extended* as "*Regex lite*".