# Regex detect line break

Tags: php, regex

I have this message (without the quotes, it's just for being precise):

```
"hey, here i am<br /><br />
 "
```

Note the white space after the line break. So here's the thing: I'm trying to remove all the invisible chars and the `<br />` of the message, all of them at the end of the message, with a regex to have something like "hey, here I am". But I must do something wrong because I can't make it work. That's what I tried:

```
$content = preg_replace('{(<br(\s*/)?>|&nbsp;|\r\n|\r|\n| )+$}i', '', $content);
```

But the message remains the same at the end. Must be something simple I missed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also HTML with regex is a bad idea.

Comment: Change `\r\n|\r|\n` to `\R`. I covered that technique [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25091724/3622940).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
([^\s\w",](?:br\W*\s*)+)"$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vM2rL7/5)**

[image]

The code is:

```
$re = "/([^\\s\\w\\",](?:br\\W*\\s*)+)\\"$/"; 
$str = "\"hey, here i am<br /> test<br /><br />\n \""; 
$subst = ''; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Works but not only with <br> :/.

Comment: @Codel96 can you post some samples of what you need? Check with this regex adding `br`: `([^\s\w",]br.*\s*)`

Comment: I'd like to remove all of the <br />, spaces and line breaks only at the end of the string. Your code works but it takes everything after the <.

Comment: @Codel96 can you check this: http://regex101.com/r/vM2rL7/3. By the way, if that doesn't match your need can you update that page and give me the link so I can help you with sample data

Comment: @Codel96 ok, check this one: http://regex101.com/r/vM2rL7/5. It takes the br at the ends as you mentioned

Comment: First, thank you for the time you're spending on it. Here's what I tested: `$content = preg_replace('#([^\s\w",](?:br\W*\s*)+)"$#', '', $content);` but didn't work.

Comment: @Codel96 check the link I gave you and take a look at the section `Code generator`. Then copy/paste the php code. You should use `$re = "/([^\\s\\w\\",](?:br\\W*\\s*)+)\\"$/"; `. Btw, if my support helps you an upvote would be appreciated :)

Comment: Oh sorry I scroleld fast and thought I already upvoted. Done.

Comment: @Codel96 did it work? Let me know so I can update the answer with solution

Comment: I tried `$re = '/([^\\s\\w\\",](?:br\\W*\\s*)+)\\"$/';` but still doesn't work. Maybe comes from the string but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Codel96 I think that something is wrong in your code. Does this link contain what you want from a regex http://regex101.com/r/vM2rL7/5 ?

Comment: Yes, it does. The string is inserted into the database but remains the same if I use a regex or not.

Comment: @Codel96 in that case then you should mark this question as solved since my answer solved your question, and open a new one related to your new problem. I've updated the answer with the fix for your question. Btw, when you create the new question send me the link.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression to do that. Use the [strip tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function to remove the tags.

```
$str = 'hey, here i am<br /><br />';
echo strip_tags($str);//yields hey, here i am
```

Don't try to write your own regular expressions to parse HTML when you have tools that already do it. Sometimes it's necessary depending on case, but in your case I would say it isn't. Just use the built in function.

Comment: I can't use stri_tags because there is some HTML in the messsage, it is posted by the user with a WYSIWYG editor. EDIT : Oh just remembered I could use strip_tags with only some tags. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: That's what "allowed tags" is for.

Comment: Well I'm already using HTMLPurifier to indicate which tags should be allowed, will be duplicated code.

Comment: @Zarathuztra: You meant probably `$allowable_tags` argument to `strip_tags()` function, as mentioned on [official docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), right?

Comment: Oh I'm tired (sorry just come from the airport) and forgot to say I want to allow <br/>, just not at the end of the message.

Comment: What editor are you using? Some of them allow you to customize exactly how the tags are used. CKEditor being one of them.

Comment: I'm using CKEditor, now I wonder if I shouldn't use <p> tags instead of <br>. Or if there's another solution I'd be interested to hear :).

Comment: @Zarathuztra Even if I shouldn't use <br>, would you know why the line break doesn't disappear at the end? Thank you ;).

Comment: You'd need to consult the CKEditor documentation. I use it, but am by no means an expert.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regular expression to do what you wanted. Take a look at this answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: I upvoted but I don't understand where it comes from too. The link you gave me was pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'hey, here i am<br /><br />';
$str=~s{(<br />|\s)*$}{}ig;
```

use this code this might help you

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cnt;    
$cnt = "hey, here i am<br /><br />";
    $cnt =~s/(<br \/>)*//isg;
print $cnt;
 output : "hey, here i am"
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.

Comment: @Stonz2 Thank you for taking the time to properly review and provide helpful comments. It really does help.