# how to replace multiline text using matlab script which uses perl

Tags: regex, perl, matlab, multiline

I came across a matlab script which uses a perl script called replaceinfile.m which uses

```
perlCmd = sprintf('"%s"',fullfile('/usr/bin/perl'));
perlstr = sprintf('%s -i.bak -pe"s/%s/%s/g" "%s"', perlCmd, str1, str2,infile);
```

and wanted to use the replaceinfile function to replace multiple lines of text, e.g.:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

becomes:

```
Line1
Line4
```

I tried

```
replaceinfile('Line2\r\nLine3\r\n','',inputfile,outputfile)
```

since there are 'CR LF' line endings in my input file but this doesn't work and I can't figure out what the correct regex is.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Try `Line1\r\n|Line2\r\n`

Comment: What exactly is the pipe doing?

Comment: @user1637359 It is an alternation. It matches either `Line1\r\n` _or_ `Line2\r\n`. See [The Stack Overflow regex reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\R` for matching all Unicode newline sequences. See this regex:

```
Line[23]\R
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR4oR8/3)!

Comment: Really glad it works for you. :) The technique of using `\R` was covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25091724/3622940) as well!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
perlstr = sprintf('%s -i.bak -pe"undef $/; s/%s/%s/g" "%s"', perlCmd, str1, str2,infile);
```

Maybe it's a good idea to change `\r` to `\r?`, then it also works with LF only files.

See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17947