# Notepad++ find and replace multiple regex expressions

Tags: regex

I found help regarding multiple search and replaces at once, but they usually cover only plain words search and replace. ([Multiple word search and replace in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946))

I have data that can have three different styles.

`(15:`

`(4:`

`(:`

Infront of each of these is a random number of spaces with I am trying to replace with a single space. I have the regular expression search for each by individually.

Find what: `*\(([0-9])([0-9])\:`

Replace with: `\(\1\2\:`

Find what: `*\(([0-9])\:`

Replace with: `\(\1\:`

Find what: `*\(\:`

Replace with: `\(\:`

If I try to combine them into a single find and replace code, I try;

Find what: `( *\(([0-9])([0-9])\:)|( *\(([0-9])\:)|( *\(\:)`

Replace with: `(?1 \(\1\2\:)(?2 \(\1\:)(?3 \(\:)`

However, this does not complete the three replaces with the desired results that occur when run individually.

What kind of adjustments do I need to make the replace code work? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
Find:  *(\(\d*:)
Replace:  \1
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG7xG8/2)