# Regular Expression remove whitespace between letters

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I messed up my html somehow and all of my html now looks like this with a whitespace between each character

```
< d i v  c l a s s = " c o l - x s - 1 2   c o l - s m - 6 " >                               
< d i v  c l a s s = " f o r m - g r o u p   c o l - x s - 1 2 "> 
< d i v  c l a s s = " r a d i o "> 
< l a b e l  c l a s s = " r a d i o - l a b e l  ">
```

It is over 2000 lines of code. I need to go back looking like this

```
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6">                               
<div class = "form-group col-xs-12" > 
<div class = "radio" > 
<label class = "radio-label" >
```

What regular expression can I use with notepad++ to fix this?

Comment: How on earth did you manage that? I'm not familiar with Notepad++ regex syntax, but you want one that will find any two non-space characters separated by a space and just delete the space (leaving the two characters). You can then go through and change double spaces to single.

Comment: I tried to do a simple find and replace all in Visual Studio and it came back 40000 occurrences changed. I couldn't even do an undo.

Comment: I've been there, and I feel your pain.

Comment: In NP++ you could also try `(?<=[^ ])[ ]` and replace with empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ doesn't support very advanced regex. Your best bet is to do a find and replace to replace two consecutive spaces with a special character that doesn't appear in your page, for example ~.

```
< d i v~c l a s s = " c o l - x s - 1 2~ c o l - s m - 6 " >~ 
< d i v~c l a s s = " f o r m - g r o u p~ c o l - x s - 1 2 "> 
< d i v~c l a s s = " r a d i o "> 
< l a b e l~c l a s s = " r a d i o - l a b e l~">
```

Now, you can replace all the spaces with the empty string to remove them:

```
<div~class="col-xs-12~col-sm-6">~
<div~class="form-group~col-xs-12">
<div~class="radio">
<label~class="radio-label~">
```

We have to replace the special character (~) with a space now, and we're done:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> 
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
<div class="radio">
<label class="radio-label ">
```

Since you mention you have Visual Studio, this is actually easier to solve with Visual Studio if you have it, since you can use a more advanced regex: Find `(\S)\s` or `(.)\s` and replace with `$1`.

If you have the TextFX plugin installed, you can run fairly complex regular expressions in notepad++ through `TextFX -> TextFX Quick -> Find/Replace`. You can run `(\S)\s` or `(.)\s` as the expression to find and use `\1` for the replace.

Comment: That did it. You are a life saver!

Comment: Mark as answer and upvote are the best way to say thanks. Glad you could recover.

Comment: np++ [uses PCRE](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) (which is advanced) but some features are not available.

Comment: Notepad++ has powerful regular expressions, perhaps you are using an old version. Notepad++ will handle the expressions at the end of your answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946 for documentation links.

Comment: I am using 6.8.3.  PCRE (most of it)is available using a plugin: `TextFX -> TextFX Quick -> Find/Replace`. However, in the find and replace dialog box, the syntax is pretty limited. The documentation linked on the question is for a C++ library. Here is the link to np++ documentation that says "if you have the plugin installed." http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions Point taken though, I should expand the answer to show how to do this replacement with the TextFX replace feature to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Find what: `(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

This will replace every space `\s` that is between two non spaces `\S`.

`(?<=\S)` is a positive lookbehind
`(?=\S)` is a positive lookahead