# Replace each match with certain value using Notepad++ in one regular expression

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I have the following code in Adobe LiveCycle Designer FormCalc:

```
if (form1.subform[0].complete_flag.rawValue == "1") then
    $.presence = "invisible";
endif
```

I want to use N++ find/replace with regular expression or similar to replace the above code to look like (to convert to JavaScript):

```
if (form1.subform[0].complete_flag.rawValue == "1") {
    this.presence = "invisible";
}
```

basically, in one run of find/replace, substitute the following:

> then ==> {
>
> $. ==> this.
>
> endif ==> }

Is this possible using N++ or similar tools?

Tarek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex:
`(then)|(\$)|(endif)`

The replace:`(?1{)(?2this)(?3})`

This will work in Notepad++.

A full explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad), but if that gets unlinked, the gist of it is this:

> The search looks for either of three alternatives separated by the `|`. Each alternative has ist own capture brackets. The replace uses the conditional form **?Ntrue-expression:false-expression** where **N** is decimal digit, the clause checks whether capture expression **N** matches.
>
> -[AdrianHHH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546871/adrianhhh)

Comment: OMG! Thanks. It worked. I searched for this extensively and I didn't find it.

Comment: Why there is a sad face next to your name above?

Comment: That's my profile picture, in the same way that you have a picture of yourself next to your name in the question (and for any answers you post).

Comment: Oh, OK. I just thought that this is related to some progress in this website.

Comment: How I can find and delete comment lines (single line comment using //)? I want to delete the entire line (remove it).

Comment: The regex would be `//.*`, and you'd replace it with a blank string. I'd suggest you consider _not_ deleting comments, though.