# How to delimit a regex group number in notepad++ replacement?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, regex-group

I want to specify a captured group then a literal digit in a replacement term, but the literal digit is being interpreted as part of the group number.

Given this (contrived) example:

```
Input text: A5
Find: (.)(.)
Replace: $16
Expected result: A6
Actual result: <blank>
```

Experimentation suggests that `$16` is being interpreted as "group 16".

I tried using `$1\6` to make the `6` literal, which gave me group 1, but a blank for the `\6` - ie the result was just `A`. `$1\\6` gave me `A\6`.

The general question is, "how do I specify group 1 then a literal number"?

Comment: You just need `${1}6`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I couldn't find any notepad++ help for that. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notepad S&R regex is powered by Boost regex library.

The unambiguous `$n` backreference is achieved with braces (`{}`) around the ID, so, you can use `${1}6` as a replacement here.

Notepad++ also supports BRE style backreferences starting with `\` (`\1`, `\2` etc. *up to `9`). So, when you use `\16` in the replacement pattern, the engine will only parse it as Backreference 1 + a literal symbol `6`. You may check it by replacing `(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)` with `\11` in `1234567890A`. Instead of the `A` (the 11th group) you will get `11` as a result. `$11` replacement would result in `A`.

[Notepad++ help](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions) mentions these notations but  it lacks details:

> `$n`, **`${n}`**, `\n`
>   Returns what matched the subexpression numbered n. Negative indices are not alowed.

Comment: Yes, because these are BRE style backreference and there are only 1 to 9 such backreferences supported.

Comment: The opening paragraph of the help page has a link (see *"on the implementer's website"*) to the full details of the regular expression language. I cannot see a link there to the replacement language, but it can be found at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html . Links to both  documents can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16104946/546871