# Multi-line search & replace for Beginning and End of Each Line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, editor, notepad++, text-editor

To start off, I want to be able to do 2 things:

**1st Thing:**

To extract foo_abc (and similarly every other line, for example, goo_zxy, and doo_fgh), I needed to remove some text appended ***BEFORE*** foo_abc, and ***AFTER*** foo_abc.

For example:

> **TEXTBEFORE**foo_abc**TEXTAFTER**
>
> **TEXTBEFORE**goo_zxy**TEXTAFTER**
>
> **TEXTBEFORE**doo_fgh**TEXTAFTER**

to obtain:

> foo_abc
>
> goo_zxy
>
> doo_fgh

**2nd Thing:**

I now need to append different text ***before*** and ***after*** foo_abc again.
Like so:

> **TextA**foo_abc**TextB**

So what I've done is:

> Find: ^
>
> Replace: **TextA**
>
> Find: $
>
> Replace: **TextB**

Which works well, but I have to perform a find&replace **TWICE** which is not very efficient. To avoid that, I found this: [Multiple word search and replace in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946)

And applied it like so:

> Find: (^)|($)
>
> Replace: (?1**TextA**)(?2**TextB**)

But it doesn't work out too well.

AND, as mentioned, I need this to work for ***EACH and every line***:
For example:

> foo_abc
>
> goo_zxy
>
> doo_fgh

I need to insert **TextA** at the beginning for each of those lines, and **TextB** at the end of each line, like so:

> **TextA**foo_abc**TextB**
>
> **TextA**goo_zxy**TextB**
>
> **TextA**doo_fgh**TextB**

Can this be done? (Yes, I actually need to do this to over 10000 lines, not just 3 and wanting an efficient way to do so).

Have I missed a quicker way to do all of this? Perhaps by performing a search and replace above in '**1st Thing**' on the **TEXTBEFORE** and **TEXTAFTER**, with **TextA** and **TextB**, respectively, in one-go?

Many thanks.

EDIT: Yes, they are literal strings. Yes, they do contain special characters because they are represent parts of a URL.

Comment: Are `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` literal strings? Try `^(TEXTBEFORE)|TEXTAFTER$` and replace with `(?{1}TextA:TextB)`

Comment: Question. Is the text you want to keep fixed, or is the before&after text you want to replace fixed?

Comment: Please, show us real cases. Are all `foo_abc` allways 3 lowercase letters, underscore, 3 lowercase letters?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My apologies, yes they are literal strings.

Comment: @LukStorms Yes they are.

Comment: @Toto No, good points you have raised, sorry. They are just segments from a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios: 1) you want to replace the `TEXTBEFORE` or `TEXTAFTER` regardless of the fact that either of them exists, 2) both `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER`  must exist

## Scenario 1

You may use a single search and replace operation for this:

*Find What*: `^(TEXTBEFORE)|TEXTAFTER$` 
*Replace With*: `(?{1}TextA:TextB)`

NOTE: If the `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` contain special chars, you may use

*Find What*: `^(\QTEXTBEFORE\E)|\QTEXTAFTER\E$`

**Details**:

- `^(TEXTBEFORE)`- match and capture into Group 1 `TEXTBEFORE` at the start of a line
- `|` - or
- `TEXTAFTER$` - match `TEXTAFTER` at the end of a line.

**Replacement pattern**:

- `(?{1}` -  if Group 1 is matched, then

  - `TextA` - return `TextA`
  - `:`  - else
  - `TextB` - replace with `TextB`
- `)` - end of the conditional replacement pattern.

[image]

## Scenario 2

If you need to match lines starting with some text and ending with another, use

*Find What*: `^TEXTBEFORE(.*?)TEXTAFTER$`
*Replace With*: `TextA$1TextB`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `TEXTBEFORE` - some text here
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (that can be referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern) matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `TEXTAFTER` - some text at the...
- `$` - end of line.

Comment: Appreciate that. Unfortunately, I can't get that to work, I presume due to the special characters in TextA and TextB. My result is (where AA represents text, and "_AA --AA-AA-AA 10 "AA_" represents TextA):
_AA --AA-AA-AA 10 "AA_**foo_abc**

Comment: `-` is not a special char outside a character class. Please post a real life example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - that's unusual as to why it didn't work then. I should have posted a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
TEXTBEFORE(.+?)TEXTAFTER
```

replace with

```
TextA$1TextB
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/1OPXHH/2/) for example and explanation

If you need to find whole line:

```
^TEXTBEFORE(.+?)TEXTAFTER$
```

Replace is the same as before.

Comment: Works very well - even with special characters. Thank you.

Comment: However, it does not find text at the start/end of a line. See my update.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for noticing - appreciate that.